# variable might not have been initialized in java

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String [] agrs){
    Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input;
    do{
        System.out.println("[ 1] Case 1.");
        System.out.println("[ 2] Case 2.");
        System.out.println("[ 3] Case 3.");
        System.out.println("[ 0] Case 0.");
        System.out.print("Your Choice: ");

        try{
            input = keyBoard.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        switch (input){
            default:
                  System.out.println("Default");
                  break;
            case 1:
                  System.out.println("One");
                  keyBoard.next();
                  break;
            case 2:
                  System.out.println("Two");
                  break;
            case 3:
                  System.out.println("Three");
                  break;
            case 0:
                  System.exit(0);
                  break;
        }
    }
    while(input != 0);
}
```

I want to make a menu in the console but taked a error.
Error: variable input might not have been initialized.
I know why i take the error but I don't know how to fix it.
I just know a little English so I expect mod edit my topic to fit more
Thank everybody

Comment: Listen to the compiler: initialize the variable that it's complaining of. Again the compiler will tell you which variable needs initializing. Note that when asking questions like this, you should show us the complete error message so that we can see what the compiler is complaining about as well.

Comment: I think int input should be initialzed to 0;

Comment: Then make a flag indicating it is not assigned with any choice .. say -1. B'coz zero is already used for exit.

Comment: Usually, and I think in this case, the uninitialized variable error is a warning to reexamine the logic, and think through what should happen when arriving at the use without having assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

This should fix your problems with endless loops and invalid inputs, and your compiler error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {

        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // This fixes the compiler error!
        int input = -1;

        do {
            System.out.println("[ 1] Case 1.");
            System.out.println("[ 2] Case 2.");
            System.out.println("[ 3] Case 3.");
            System.out.println("[ 0] Case 0.");
            System.out.print("Your Choice: ");

            try {
                input = keyBoard.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                // This fixes the endless loops on invalid inputs!
                System.out.println("Invalid input " + keyBoard.next());
                input = -1;
            }

            switch (input) {
                default:
                    System.out.println("Default");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("One");
                    keyBoard.next();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Two");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Three");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        } while (input != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've posted a more complete solution, even you have only asked about the problem with the compiler! The endless loop was coming only when you enter non integer values, which you have to remove with `next()` otherwise you'll catch the invalid input again and again.

Comment: I can't check mark for your answer. But i not enough reputation.
I'll check mark in other time

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that an exception may be thrown from 'keyBoard.nextInt()' before input is actually assigned. If thats the case then think about what happens in the switch statement below... or even worse, how do you ever exit from the do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize int input with 0 or any value.Because it get input from user before the use of variable input.

```
int input=0;
```

It will solves your problem .

Answer (score 0):

this should fix it,

`int input = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize a variable before you used it..

```
int input;
```

You can initialize this variable with some dummy value:

```
int input = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the input variable to some default value. It is a local variable, and local variables are not initialized by default. So you need to explicitly assign some default value to them.

Check this out :

```
        int input;
    do{
      // Some statements
        try {
            input = keyBoard.nextInt();
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        // What if the above try-catch block is bypassed. In that case input will not have any value assigned to it. 
        // Hence, you get the error
        switch (input){
```

So change the first statement as follows :

```
int input = -1;
```

Comment: Change into int input=-1. When i enter a character that type isn't int, I will endless loop

Comment: You already have 0 as one of the case. So if the try-catch is bypassed, then none of the switch case must be executed or a default case must get invoked. Hence, better your initialize it to a value which is not one of your switch case values.